# Selichos in Shachris Mussaf and Mincha of Yom Kippur

Tags: yom-kippur, selichot

The Tur O.C. 620 quotes from his father the Rosh (Yoma siman 19, 20) various practices about saying Selichos on Yom Kippur. These are quoted from Geonic responsa and from the Raaviah. Yet almost no one says them, and no machzorim print them. The few communities that do say them hand out booklets. When did the practice of saying selichos on Yom Kippur stop?

Comment: I think you need to edit in more precisely what you mean by "Selichot". Every prayer on Yom Kippur has elements from Selichot that include *Shema Koleinu*, *Zechor* and *Ashamnu*. If you're referring specifically to 13 Middot, then state this.